# Speak up a query very slow- reduce parameters speed up a query

Tags: mysql, optimization

I know this is a general question.

The below query is very slow. I have indexing on all the where statements. I could do with some advice on speeding it up:

1. If i pass in less parameters and have these directly in the query i loose flexibility- does this speed up the query.
2. is there a quicker way of selecting on having. I dont neccessarily need to select the column. Can i simple query on having where the column is not in the select as in the case of tags, sets
3. are subqueries in select statements slower than performing join- can i optimise the address count in the first select to improve things.

Any advice most helpful

```
BEGIN

DECLARE user_id int;
SET user_id =(SELECT im.user_id FROM image im WHERE im.id = in_image_id);

/*Image details*/
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN im.id, im.alias_title, im.title,im.guid_id, im.description, im.hits, im.show_comment, im.can_print, im.can_download, im.can_share, im.created_on, im.date_taken, im.approved, im.visible,
(SELECT count(*) from image where image.address_id = im.address_id) as address_count,
ad.id as image_address_id, ad.address_line_1, ad.address_line_2, ad.town_village_city, ad.state_province_county, ad.postal_code, ad.other_address_detail, co.country,
geo.latitude, geo.longitude, geo.zoom, geo.yaw, geo.pitch,
c.make, c.model,
us.first_name, us.surname, uf.user_id, uf.real_name, uf.user_name, uf.gender, uf.description as user_description, uf.buddy_icon_url, uf.first_taken_date, uf.first_date,
uf.time_zone_label, uf.time_zone_offset,
adf.id as user_address_id,
adf.address_line_1 as user_address_line_1, adf.address_line_2 as user_address_line_2, adf.town_village_city as user_town_village_city, adf.state_province_county as user_state_province_county, 
adf.postal_code as user_postal_code, adf.other_address_detail as user_other_address_detail, cof.country as user_country,
geof.latitude as user_geolocation_latitude, geof.longitude as user_geolocation_longitude, geof.zoom as user_geolocation_zoom, geof.yaw as user_geolocation_yaw, geof.pitch as user_geolocation_pitch,
im.id = in_image_id AS image_selected -- image selected
FROM image im
LEFT JOIN address ad ON im.address_id = ad.id
LEFT JOIN country co ON ad.country_id = co.id
LEFT JOIN geolocation geo ON im.geolocation_id = geo.id
LEFT JOIN camera c ON im.camera_id = c.id
INNER JOIN user us ON im.user_id = us.id
LEFT JOIN user_flickr uf ON us.id = uf.id
LEFT JOIN address adf ON uf.address_id =adf.id
LEFT JOIN country cof ON ad.country_id = cof.id
LEFT JOIN geolocation geof ON uf.geolocation_id = geof.id
WHERE im.user_id = user_id
AND im.approved = in_image_approved 
AND im.visible = in_image_visible
AND (im.advertise_to <= NOW() OR im.advertise_to IS NULL)
ORDER BY image_selected  DESC, date_taken DESC;

/* Select albums for a user and albums the image belongs to */
SELECT a.alias_title, a.title, a.hits, a.created_on, a.updated_on, a.updated_by,
       im.id = in_image_id AS image_albums  -- album belongs to
FROM   album       a
  JOIN album_image ai ON a.id        = ai.album_id
  JOIN image       im ON ai.image_id = im.id
WHERE  a.user_id = user_id
   AND a.approved = in_album_approved
   AND a.visible  = in_album_visible
GROUP BY alias_title
ORDER BY image_albums DESC;

/*Tags*/
SELECT ta.id, ta.raw,ta.title, ta.hits as tag_hits, it.hits as image_tag_hits,
(SELECT count(*) from image_tag where image_tag.tag_title_id = ta.id) as tag_count
FROM tag_title ta
INNER JOIN image_tag it ON ta.id = it.tag_title_id
INNER JOIN image im ON it.image_id = im.id
WHERE im.id = in_image_id HAVING tag_count >1;

/*Comments*/
SELECT fc.comment_html, fc.author_user_id, fc.author_user_name,
         fc.permalink, fc.author_buddy_icon
         FROM flickr_comment fc
INNER JOIN image_flickr_comment ifc ON fc.id = ifc.comment_id
INNER JOIN image im ON ifc.image_id = im.id; 

/*Sets*/
SELECT ms.alias_title, ms.title, ms.photo_set_small_url,
(SELECT count(*) from image_media_set where image_media_set.media_set_id = ms.id) as media_set_count
FROM media_set ms
INNER JOIN image_media_set ims ON ms.id = ims.media_set_id
INNER JOIN image im ON ims.image_id = im.id
WHERE im.id = in_image_id HAVING media_set_count >1; 

/*Media Galleries*/
SELECT mg.alias_title, mg.title, mg.primary_photo_medium_url, 
(SELECT count(*) from image_media_gallery where image_media_gallery.media_gallery_id = mg.id) as media_gallery_count
FROM media_gallery mg 
INNER JOIN image_media_gallery img ON mg.id = img.media_gallery_id
INNER JOIN image im ON img.image_id = im.id
WHERE im.id = in_image_id HAVING media_gallery_count >1;

/*Media Groups*/
/*SELECT mg.alias_title, mg.name, mg.icon_url FROM media_group mg 
INNER JOIN image_media_group img ON mg.id = img.media_group_id
INNER JOIN image im ON img.image_id = im.id
WHERE im.id = in_image_id;*/

SELECT mg.alias_title, mg.name, mg.icon_url,
(SELECT count(*) from image_media_group where image_media_group.media_group_id = mg.id) as media_group_count
FROM media_group mg 
INNER JOIN image_media_group img ON mg.id = img.media_group_id
INNER JOIN image im ON img.image_id = im.id
WHERE im.id = in_image_id HAVING media_group_count >1;

END
```

Comment: You should start by finding out where the bottleneck is, by looking at the query execution plan for what step takes up the most of the time.

Comment: You say "below query" (singular) but there are nine queries there (including one that has been commented out). Which one is slow in particular? Try timing them all individually.

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions.**  Diagnosing slow queries requires full table and index definitions, not just a description or paraphrase.  Maybe your tables are defined poorly.  Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did.   Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell.  If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN`, put the results in the question as well.

Comment: As @halfer mentioned, you should isolate the slow part first. Furthermore I am not an expert but I think that point 1 won't have much impact on performance. Besides this, it may be interesting to try what will happen if you first remove all records with insufficient count as it would simplify the query.